Getthreadcontext return value True
return is True
but Context is all zeros
I am correctly receiving debug events
this is on Windows 7 32 bit
i am try to write a simple debugger.
also tried wow64 context structure but not wow64 structure
as this is a 32 bit version windows 7

you need to set the context flag member of the context flag structure to 0x10003F to return all information this is not mentioned explicitly in the documentation. This solved my problem.
